# Call Stripe Product into Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I´m working in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application MVC

Actually I integrate Stripe checkout to my project using [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet), but into Stripe dashboard I can see we can create products, so I think we can call products from .Net but how we can call them using ASP.NET Core?

There is an image of what I´m talking about

[Stripe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vY87.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StripeProductService` within the stripe nuget package.

```
var productService = new StripeProductService();
StripeList<StripeProduct> productItems = productService.List();
```

That will give you a list of all products stored in stripe. The full documentation is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#list_products